# How to customize tooltip and slicer values in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am unpivoting few columns which are extracted from a Date field, to show as a radio button in the slicer.(fields are: "Daily", "Yearly", "monthly", "quarterly")
Qs.1: Can I show these values in a custom order like: "yearly", "quarterly", "monthly", "Daily"
[image]

Data format( I have used the "Attribute" column  in the slicer to achieve the radio buttons)
[image]

Qs.2: To sort the x-axis I have used the main date field("app_submitted_date) on the tooltip.
If I don't use the "app_submitted_date" on tooltip will not be able to sort x-axis when "quarterly" & "monthly" is chosen. 
While using the "app_submitted_date" filed on tooltip I am getting the tooltip in the following format:
[image]

How to customize the tooltip so that it will only show ( Female: count, Male: Count, Not Disclosed: count, Date: whatever date it is)
Please let me know for any clarification in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Qs-1 Solution

Create a small table with two columns & 4 rows :

1. Attribute Names
2. Index

as follows :

```
| Year      | 1 |
| Quater    | 2 |
| Month     | 3 |
| Daily     | 4 |
```

Then, create a 1 to many relation between this table and the table that you showed in the question (Attribute to Attribute connect).

Then, instead of take the contents of this attribute column as a filter and prior to that sort this attribute column by index in the "Table View".

## Qs-2 Solution

For this solution, I agree with the answer provided by Jon. There is no way to hide the thing that you have taken in tool tip; as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the tool tip directly as you have suggested cannot be done, however there is a work around with '[Tool Tip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-tooltips)' pages, that may help you show what you need.

You create a new page, with the measures in, this is then displayed as a tooltip over your data. Image taken from the MS Docs website

[image]